# Json Pipe - unable to set field to empty

Tags: javascript, html, angular, filter, ngmodel

I'm using a **json pipe** filter in my angular app.
The problem is when I try to reset the field by setting the value to `null` or an ''(empty string) the pipe literally displays `null` or `''`.

How do I properly clear my field?

```
 <div>
  <textarea [ngModel]="myJson| json" (ngModelChange)="update($event)" 
cols="200" rows="20"></textarea>
</div>
<button (click)="clear()"> Clear</button>
```

**.TS**

```
clear(){ 
   this.myJson = null // returns 'null'
   this.myJson = '': //returns ''
   this.myJson = {}; //returns {}
}
```

Comment: it should be empty object ?.

Comment: I tried that to but it just displayed the brackets

Comment: what do you mean by **'clear my field'** here ?

Comment: nothin should be displayed in the text area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `undefined` here in this case you would get an empty field

```
clear(){ 
   this.myJson = undefined;
}
```